# Automaticall adding to the module path using -NoProfile from command line

Tags: powershell, module, scheduled-tasks, command-line-arguments, profile

My modules can't live in the standard module directories on our servers.  They must live on the E: drive.

For development, I can modify my profile to modify the $ENV:PSModulePath variable. But when I schedule a script and call PowerShell from the command line we are instructed to use the -NOProfile switch. A typical example would be:

```
 New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -Argument "-windowstyle hidden -NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -File `"<Path to Script>`""
```

How can I include modifying the Module path from the command line so that my scripts can find their modules without specifying that path in every script?

Comment: You could permanently modify the environment variable on the local machine as that is just stored as a key in the registry. That said it's better practice to define in your script the resources that it needs to run without relying the outside workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stop using the `-NoProfile` switch, since in this case you want to use it.

You could use the `-Command` switch instead of `-File` (and then dot source the script):

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "$env:PSModulePath = (($env:PSModulePath -split ';') + 'E:\Your\Module\Path') -join ';' ; . '<Path to Script>'
```

Comment: I used your -Command option suggestion and it works great.  Thank you!